# Improve OCR result

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I am working on project which base on detecton of license plates from video.

This is how it looks like:
[image]

My problem starts when I want to use OCR on the car plate. I was testing it on some pictures and it works really nice. Here is some example:
[image]

But when I put my detected plate the result is very bad:

[image]

So I want to ask you if you have some advise for me how improve OCR results?

Here is how I get binary image:

```
cv::Mat equalized;
    cv::equalizeHist(gray, equalized);
    cv::imshow("Hist. Eq.", equalized);

    /* Bilateral filter helps to improve the segmentation process */

    cv::Mat blur;
    cv::bilateralFilter(equalized, blur, 9, 75, 75);
    cv::imshow("Filter", blur);


    /* Threshold to binarize the image */

    cv::Mat thres;
    cv::adaptiveThreshold(blur, thres, 255, cv::ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv::THRESH_BINARY, 15, 2); //15, 2
    cv::imshow("Threshold", thres);
```

Maybe some more filters? If it will be helpful I can put more code.

My first idea was getting a little bit bigger rect with my plate.

Here is how I get vector with my rects:

```
std::vector< std::vector< cv::Point> > LP_contours;
    cv::findContours(img_threshold, LP_contours, 0, 1);
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours_poly(LP_contours.size());
    for (int ii = 0; ii < LP_contours.size(); ii++)
        if (LP_contours[ii].size() > 100 && contourArea(LP_contours[ii]) > 3000 && contourArea(LP_contours[ii]) < 10000) 
        {
            cv::approxPolyDP(cv::Mat(LP_contours[ii]), contours_poly[ii], 3, true);
            cv::Rect appRect(boundingRect(cv::Mat(contours_poly[ii])));

            if (appRect.width > appRect.height && appRect.width>160 && appRect.width < 190 && appRect.height>40 && appRect.height < 60)
                boundRect.push_back(appRect);
        }
```

I want change size of appRect by simple code:

```
appRect.height += 10;
appRect.width += 10;
```

But it doesn't work. I am new in openCV and I have problem with this kind of staff. Have you some advise how to get bigger rect?

Thank you for all your time and help.

Comment: OCR from on-screen text is just about as good as it gets - consistent font size, everything at a consistent angle, all characters the same size, no noise, excellent contrast.  Your licence plate has noise, the contrast in the original is quite poor, the text isn't aligned to the box.  Your biggest problem seems to be that it is trying to OCR the frame - and this is confusing it.  Can you remove the frame somehow?

Comment: I was hoping that you help me a liitle bit with it. I am thinking about remove frame, use a littile bit perspective transformation and maybe some better filter? But it is not so easy for me :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified snippet how you can manually change the boundRect parameters to achieve the desired ROI in openCV :

```
int main()
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("car.jpg",0);

    cv::Rect boundRect{ 200,164,140,25 };
    cv::Mat cropped_image = image(boundRect);

    cv::namedWindow("Image");
    cv::imshow("Image", image);

    cv::namedWindow("Original cropped Image");
    cv::imshow("Original cropped Image", cropped_image);

    cv::Rect new_boundRect = boundRect;
    new_boundRect.x += 10;
    new_boundRect.y += 2;
    new_boundRect.width -= 10;
    new_boundRect.height -= 10;

    cv::Mat new_cropped_image = image(new_boundRect);
    cv::namedWindow("New cropped Image");
    cv::imshow("New cropped Image", new_cropped_image);

    cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Picture:

[image]